# writing buffer to a file - how can I keep binary format?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code in coffescript:

```
fs = require 'fs'

class PpmCanvas


  constructor: (@width, @height, @fileName) ->
        size = @width * @height * 3

        array = new Uint8ClampedArray size
        @buffer = new Buffer array

        for element, index in @buffer
            @buffer.writeUInt8 128, index


    plot: (x, y, r, g, b) ->
        true

    save: () -> 
        header = new Buffer "P6 #{@width} #{@height} 255\n"

        together = Buffer.concat([header, @buffer])

        fs.open @fileName, 'w', (err, fd) =>
            if err
                throw err

            fs.write fd, together.toString(), undefined, undefined, (err, written, buffer ) =>
                fs.close fd
canvas = new PpmCanvas 200, 200, 'image.ppm'
canvas.save()
```

I'm trying to make a ppm image class, and I have a problem with saving the image to disk. So I first create Uint8Clamped array to keep the pixels data, then wrap it with a Buffer to be able to write it to disk later. And I set all pixels to some value to have some initial color in a loop. And as long as the value is in range 0..127 everything is fine, every byte is written to file as one byte, but when the value is bigger then 127 - every byte is written as 2 bytes to disk and it breaks the image. I've been trying to set the buffer encoding to 'binary' and everything else but it still gets written as two bytes - so plz tell me what is the correct way to write binary data to disk using node.

Comment: What happens if you just write `together` without the `.toString()` part?

Comment: @loganfsmyth: the file has 0 length

Comment: It looks like you are missing an argument for `fs.write` and I'm not sure how it will react to `undefined`. Maybe try `fs.write fd, together, 0, together.length, 0, (err, written, buffer) ->`. Any reason you aren't just using `writeFile`? `fs.writeFile @fileName, together`

Comment: @loganfsmyth: actually it helped, fs.write with propper arguments, and writeFile - works as well. Thanks a lot, plz make an answer, I'll accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.write` expects its arguments to be a Buffer. You are also missing an argument. Really you should just use `fs.writeFile` for simplicity though.

```
// Add the missing 3rd arg and don't use 'undefined'.
fs.write fd, together, 0, together.length, 0, (err, written, buffer) ->

// Or just use this and drop the 'fs.open' call.
fs.writeFile @fileName, together
```